# Trouble accessing a custom form on magento(multiple website) from url

Tags: magento

I created a custom web form for a magento website, on a local server which has only one website setup, i could access the form using the URL but when i upload the module to the server which has multiple website setup, i cannot access the form using the URl ,
for e.g on my local server i could access the form as

```
  http://localhost/cars/index.php/surcontest-contest
```

but when i upload the module e.g dev.test.org on the server(it has multiple website setup, more than 50 sites ) i could not access the form

```
 http://dev.test.org/surcontest-contest (gives me a 404 error)
```

how would i access the module, how would i find out about the url to access the form.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1) clean cache to make sure that module installed (check it in admin or database)

2) check that url rewrites enabled and works (can you access some category or product page without index.php ?)

Comment: Ya i tried cleaning the cache, and the module shows up in the admin

Comment: i can see the module enabled in configuraion>Advanced>

Comment: i have tried both 
http://dev.test.org/surcontest-contest
as well as
http://dev.test.org/index.php/surcontest-contest
both gives me 404 error

Comment: maybe there are no layout or controller. try to enable logs at System>Configuration>Developer>Logs

Comment: refresh page and watch for files at var/log magento folder

Answer (score 0):

If your default URL is  http://www.test.org/ then to access multiple sub domain you should enable from your domain panel by providing host stetting 
Hostname=*.test.org, address=, Record Type=A(address)

Also, on your server add sub domain dev.test.org.
It will create dev folder in the public_html folder in file manager.

You should copy index.php and .htaccess file in that follows the magento multiple web site steps see the link 
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-set-multiple-websites-with-multiple-store-views-in-magento/